# Angular ui modal showing up at the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I've been trying to get the modal window sin angular ui working, and I've been having difficulty. I'm still pretty new to this

I added

```
"angular-ui": null,
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0"
```

to bower and ran bower install

In the index.html,
I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.css"/>    
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Currently I just have an ng-click set to open the modal window with

```
$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/post-modal.html',
                controller: 'PostModalController',
                size: 'lg'
            })
```

My modal view is also pretty simple, just

```
<div>
<form name="postForm">
    <textarea type="text" name="content" ng-model="postInput"></textarea>
</form>
{{postInput}}
```

So far it just adds the div to the bottom of the screen each time I click the link. I think its a problem with my styles, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: This is for sure problem with your styles. And it's hard to help you in this case unless you replicate the issue in the demo.

Comment: I wonder if the is some step to installing ui that I'm missing. Perhaps a case file I didn't include?

Comment: Did you add Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: That seems like it would be the problem. Is there a bower for it? It doesn't seem to be in the angular-bootstrap folder

Comment: Ahh thanks, I thought that angular-bootstrap or angular-ui would have bootstrap set as a dependancy or something.

Comment: No, you still need to include bootstrap css.